# WiFi connection loss on Galaxy S2 I9100G

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

After upgrade from stock 2.6.3 to Stock ICS4.0.3 (XXLPQ) WiFi disconnects after a few seconds. Disabling and enabling WiFi helps for a few seconds only.

Has anyone experienced this? How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you once check your wifi sleep policy?